# Connect to Office365 Exchange Server with ews-java-api-2.0.jar in Core JAVA

Tags: java, office365, exchangewebservices

I am using ews-java-api-2.0.jar, to connect to office365 and below is the sample code:

```
package javaapplication6;

import java.net.URI;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.property.WellKnownFolderName;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.folder.Folder;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.WebCredentials;

public class JavaApplication6 {

    public static class RedirectionUrlCallback implements IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl {
        public boolean autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback(String redirectionUrl) {
          return redirectionUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
        }
    }

    public static ExchangeService connectViaExchangeManually(String email, String password)
      throws Exception {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(email, password);
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        service.setTraceEnabled(true);
        Folder inbox = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
        System.out.println("messages: " + inbox.getTotalCount());
        return service;
    }

    public static ExchangeService connectViaExchangeAutodiscover(String email, String password) {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        try {
            service.setCredentials(new WebCredentials(email, password));
            service.autodiscoverUrl(email, new RedirectionUrlCallback());
            service.setTraceEnabled(true);
            Folder inbox = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
            System.out.println("messages: " + inbox.getTotalCount());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return service;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        ExchangeService service = connectViaExchangeManually("<name>@<company>.onmicrosoft.com", "<password>");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

}
```

When i run this code from Netbeans IDE , getting below error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/Lookup
    at javaapplication6.JavaApplication6.connectViaExchangeAutodiscover(JavaApplication6.java:33)
    at javaapplication6.JavaApplication6.main(JavaApplication6.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.Lookup
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
C:\Users\Brijesh Jalan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I am stuck here since 2 days, any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: The error is very clear: ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.http.config.Lookup

Comment: after referring the following JARs, it got resolved.
EWSJavaAPI_1.2original.jar, EWSJavaAPIWithJars_1.2.1.jar, httpclient-4.2.5.jar, httpcore-4.2.4.jar, jcifs-1.3.17.jar, commons-codec-1.7.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Comment: Jan 27, 2016 8:23:03 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: Basic authentication scheme selected
Jan 27, 2016 8:23:09 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector processWWWAuthChallenge
INFO: Failure authenticating with BASIC ''@outlook.office365.com:443 microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EWSHttpException: Connection not established
 at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.HttpClientWebRequest.throwIfConnIsNull(Unknown Source)
 at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.HttpClientWebRequest.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)

Comment: I am getting above error now. what could be the error?

Comment: How did you solve that? Am using exactly the same thing but still getting 401

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi   add following jar files

```
EWSJavaAPI_1.2original.jar
EWSJavaAPIWithJars_1.2.1.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
jcifs-1.3.17.jar
commons-codec-1.7.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

to resolve all dependencies .You need to open the URL in chrome browser -

`https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`

Then enter UserName and Password of your authenticating credentials which you are going to use in your below code.

```
package EWSJavaAPI;

import java.net.URI;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WellKnownFolderName;

public class EWSJavaAPI {

    public static class RedirectionUrlCallback implements IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl {
        public boolean autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback(String redirectionUrl) {
          return redirectionUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
        }
    }

    public static ExchangeService connectViaExchangeAutodiscover(String email, String password) {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        try {

            service.setCredentials(new WebCredentials(email, password));
            service.autodiscoverUrl(email, new RedirectionUrlCallback());
            service.setTraceEnabled(true);
            Folder inbox = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
            System.out.println("messages: " + inbox.getTotalCount());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return service;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          System.out.println("Hello World");
          ExchangeService service = connectViaExchangeAutodiscover("user@domain.com", "xxxxxx");

      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

It works pretty well at my end with Office365.

Comment: I am able to connect to my Office365 exchange and able to bind Inbox. Appreciated!!

Comment: Hi I tried above code to communicate with office 365 server ,but I am getting "(401) Unauthorized" . Same credentials are working when we are accessing account using webapp.   Can you please let us know when this error occurs ?

Comment: Try with manual discover and let me know if you get success: public Static void connectViaExchangeManually(String email, String password) { try {
            ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(email, password);
            service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
            service.setCredentials(credentials);           
            EWSResponse = "SUCCESS";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            EWSResponse = "FAILURE: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located";
        }
    }

Comment: Hi Dhananjay, Thanks for your reply.  Yes I get "Success" but the moment I try to bind it with the mailbox to perform any mail related activity it says, "401 Unauthorized"  Can you let me know what I am missing ?

Comment: Rohan, please add inline code and let me know what output you are getting. Also you need to use exact 7 jars mentioned in above answer. Just tested it works fine at my end.private static ExchangeService service;service.setTraceEnabled(true);
System.out.println("|---------------------> service = " + service);Folder inbox = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
System.out.println("messages: " + inbox.getTotalCount());

Comment: @VipinS : How to get messages from public shared folders?Can you check if it working if you change line in source WellKnownFolderName.Inbox with WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot. I am getting Error as There are no public folder servers available.

Comment: Am trying to use corp id but it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody help?